# Why is this loop not looping?

Tags: c++

I need to do this: Open a user-specified file for input. Prompt for the name of the file, read it into a string variable, echo print it to the terminal and then open it. If the file is not successfully opened, enter into a loop that prints out an error message, resets the input file stream variable (Input_file_stream_var.clear(); Where Input_file_stream_var is the name of your input file stream variable), obtains a new file name and tries to open the new file. The loop continues until the user successfully enters a valid file name or presses ctrl-c to exit.

and here is the code that i have so far but i cant get it to loop back into the process if the file was not opened.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Variables
    char test;
    string  infname, outfname;
    fstream infile, outfile;
    do
    {
        // Propt for and echo print input file
        cout << endl << "Enter the name of the input file: ";
        cin >> infname;
        cout << infname << endl;

        infile.open(infname.c_str());

        // Test if file opened
        if(!infile)
        {
            cout << string(12,'*') << " File Open Error " << string(12,'*') << endl;
            cout << "==> Input file failed to open properly!!\n";
            cout << "==> Attempted to open file: " << infname << endl;
            cout << "==> Please try again...\n";
            cout << string(41,'*') << endl;
            infile.clear();
            return 1;
        }
     } while(!infile.is_open());    

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return 1` statement is causing your program to exit: you are returning from `main()`

Just don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `return 1` or changing it to `continue`. `return 1` returns code execution from `main` and not the loop.